# After setting networkingMode=mirrored in WSL, vscode cannot launch Node.js projects using launch.json vscode debug

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

**VERSION**

```
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.3155
```

**.wslconfig**

```
[wsl2]
autoProxy=true
dnsTunneling=true
firewall=true
networkingMode=mirrored # nat | mirrored
[experimental]
autoMemoryReclaim=gradual  # gradual  | dropcache | disabled
```

**Description of the problem**

When using vscode and configuring launch.json to start the program, it takes a long time to execute.When setting networkingMode to nat, this issue doesn't occur.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpJcf.png)

How to enable vscode debugging properly while networkingMode is set to mirrored mode.

Comment: Based on the request over on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#mirrored-mode-networking, you probably want to file/ask this over on https://github.com/microsoft/wsl